# How Would i change the content of a webpage with the Onclick Function using a function

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function changecontent(description){
     console.log(description);
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = description;
}
```

```html
<body>


<div class="editingfunction">
<ul style="list-style-type:none">

<li>Please Mouse Over Subject</li>
<li onClick="changecontent();">Math</li>
<li onClick="changecontent();">Science</li>
<li onClick="changecontent();">Geography</li>
<li onClick="changecontent();">Arts</li>
<li onClick="changecontent();">Buisness</li>
<li onClick="changecontent();">Health</li>
<li onClick="changecontent();">Social Science</li>

</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>
</body>
```

I'm planning to make multiple layouts for the page and based on which item is clicked the content should be changed accordingly. The problem is that I don't know how to make the java function change the content differently based on which item is clicked...

Comment: Well, `changecontent(description)` takes 1 parameter, but you have given none `onClick="changecontent();"`. Send a parameter.

Comment: I know I haven't but I was wondering how I would add multiple parameters but based on an elements' id...

Comment: Use `this.id` or something similar then?

Comment: where would I enter the id i'm using? in changecontent() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand you correctly, you have several descriptive texts for each of your subjects that you want to dynamically insert into #content. You could just store your texts in variables:

```
var mathDesc = "Math is awesome and <b>not scary at all!</b>";
```

You could then insert it to #content like this:

```
<li onClick="changecontent(mathDesc);">Math</li>
```

Personally I would use a different approach: Having multiple content-divs and hiding all but one at each time.

---

One way to hide content is to programmatically assign a className, e.g. `hidden` and to assign `display:none` as CSS rule to that class.

Below is an example snippet. I identified the content based on the list-item-id, which I think is what you wish to do.

```js
function changeContent(id) {
  var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].id === id + "Content") {
      content[i].classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
      content[i].classList.add("hidden");
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("chooseSubject").onclick = function(e) {
  changeContent(e.target.id);
}
```

```css
#chooseSubject {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#chooseSubject li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#chooseSubject li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(267, 214, 269);
}
#chooseSubject li:active {
  background-color: rgb(167, 114, 169);
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="chooseSubject">
  <li id="Math">Math</li>
  <li id="Science">Science</li>
  <li id="Geography">Geography</li>
  <li id="Arts">Arts</li>
</ul>
<div id="MathContent" class="content hidden">
  Math is awesome and <b>not scary at all!</b>
</div>
<div id="ScienceContent" class="content hidden">
  Science is like math but less exact and more hands-on.
</div>
<div id="GeographyContent" class="content hidden">
  You know.. Countries, cities, rivers and stuff.
</div>
<div id="ArtsContent" class="content hidden">
  You learn about things that have no function in Arts.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

can you make something like this:

```
<li onClick="changecontent('Math');">Math</li>
```

this should work..

Comment: This are the right quotes in this case; changecontent(' ... ')

Comment: sorry I may not have been very clear, I know that the description parameter works that way but I would like to change the content of the page, and that code would be elsewhere under a different id. Could you help me?

Comment: Hi Toni, you can work with 2 or more parameters like this:

function changecontent(title, description){
     console.log(title +' '+ description);
     document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = title +' '+ description;
}

<li data-title="Hello Title" data-text="Hello Content Text..." onClick="changecontent(this.data-title, this.data-text);">Math</li>

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass description param to the method like this way

```
<li onClick="changecontent("Math");">Math</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, sorry my question was vague im quite new at this kind of thing....

```js
<script>
    function changecontent(clicked_id){


     alert(clicked_id);
    }


    </script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>





}
.editingfunction{
background-color: ;
text-decoration-color: white;
border :none;
opacity: 0.4;
width: 100px;


}
.col:active {
background-color: rgb(167,114,169);
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration-color:red; 
}

.col:visited
{
text-decoration-color:red; 



}








body {

background: ;
font-family:  ;
text-decoration-color: white;

}










</style>





</head>
<body>



 
<div class="editingfunction">
<ul style="list-style-type:none">

<li>Please Click Subject</li>
<li class="col" id="Math" onClick="changecontent(this.id);">Math</li>
<li class="col" id="Science" onClick="changecontent(this.id);">Science</li>
<li class="col" id="Geography" onClick="changecontent(this.id);">Geography</li>
<li class="col" id="Arts" onClick="changecontent(this.id);">Arts</li>
<li class="col" id="Buisness" onClick="changecontent(this.id);">Buisness</li>
<li class="col" id="Health" onClick="changecontent(this.id);">Health</li>
<li class="col" id="Social_Science" onClick="changecontent(this.id);">Social Science</li>

</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>
</body>
</html>



<!-- begin snippet: js hide:false -->
```